# how to sum a column after SortBy[...]

Tags: data, sorting

Given a dataset:

```
dataset =
  {{AFR, SouthAfrica, 2, -3, 4, -5},
  {ASIA, Brunei, 2, -3, 4, -6},
  {EU, Austria, 1, -3, 4, -6},
  {EU, Belgium, 2, -3, 4, -7},
  {ASIA, Cambodia, 2, -3, 4, 4},
  {AUS, Australia, 1, -3, 4, 5},
  {AUS, NewZealand, 2, -3, 4, -5},
  {EU, Bulgaria, 2, -3, 4, -8},
  {LAM, Colombia, 2, -3, 4, -5},
  {EU, Croatia, 2, -3, 4, 9},
  {EU, Cyprus, 2, -3, 4, -5},
  {LAM, Argentina, 2, -3, 4, -5},
  {LAM, Brazil, 3, -3, 7, -5},
  {ASIA, China1, 2, -3, 4, 4},
  {ASIA, Indonesia, 2, -3, 4, -4},
  {LAM, Chile, 2, -3, 6, -5},
  {LAM, CostaRica, 1, -2, 4, -5}};

sdata=SortBy[dataset, First];
```

The first column defines regions, and I like to sum the elements in the 3rd and 5th columns by region. I like to have a table of regional sums by the 3rd and 5th columns (please note: I do not mean the summation of the 3rd and 5th columns).

Eventually, the table I like to create will have three columns: Regional names (1st column), regional sums of the 3rd column (2nd column), and regional sums of the 5th column (3rd column).

Comment: you meant _sum the elements in the **3rd** and 5th columns_?

Comment: @kglr: Sorry for my mistake. As you noted, I meant the elements in the 3rd and 5th columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dataset @ GroupBy[SortBy[First] @ dataset, First -> (#[[{3, 5}]] &), 
  AssociationThread[{"column 3", "column 5"}, Total @ #] &]
```

[image]

```
Dataset @ Values @
  GroupBy[SortBy[First] @ dataset, First -> (#[[{1, 3, 5}]] &), 
   AssociationThread[{"Region", "column 3", "column 5"}, 
     Prepend[Total[Rest /@ #], #[[1, 1]]]] &]
```

[image]

You can also create a `Dataset` object from `dataset` first and  use `Query`:

```
keys = {"Region", "Country", "column 3", "column 4", "column 5", "column 6"};

ds = Dataset @ Map[AssociationThread[keys, #] &] @ SortBy[First] @ dataset
```

[image]

```
ds[GroupBy[#, First -> Rest, Total] &, {"Region", "column 3", "column 5"}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Dataset`creation is really handy. Thanks a lot.